# Как извлечь данные из поля JSONB и объеденить их?

Tags: postgresql

Имеется таблица с jsonb полем

```
Table user_goods
  + id int
  + goods jsonb
```

Например

```
id 100
goods [ 123: {name: "car", weight: 1024}, 456: {name: "bike", weight: 500} ]

id 200
goods [ 999: {name: "rat", weight: 0.5}, 555: {name: "dog", weight: 15} ]
```

Как можно написать запрос, чтобы получить для всех записей из таблицы user_goods составить список вещей в таком формате?

```
[
  {name: "car", weight: 1024},
  {name: "bike", weight: 500},
  {name: "rat", weight: 0.5},
  {name: "dog", weight: 15}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать, например так

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(goods.value)
FROM user_goods, jsonb_each(user_goods.goods) AS goods
-- WHERE goods.value->>'weight' = '1' можно еще добавить условие отбора
```